# How to scrape a facebook user profile page

Tags: php, facebook

I like to know how to scrape a facebook user profile page using php. I tried using CURL, fsockopen and file_get_contents but it is not returning the processed HTML page. It just return only the HTML page filled with JS code. It seems that, the facebook loading the page using the Javascript. So, I want to know, how to get the processed HTML page using php.

NOTE: 
1. logout from facebook.
2. Hit a user URL eg: http://www.facbook.com/USERNAME

Comment: Can you a bit more clear about what exactly you need and its purpose??

Comment: I realized that facebook checks the user agent. So you have to set the header of the request of your script too.

Comment: @kvijayhari: I just want to scrap the user likes from the page

Comment: @esel: I tried with non-javascript user agent, the page itself return blank. no output. just try disabling browser javascript and try the user URL. The page will never load.

Comment: I'm not sure this is so easy, since facebook construct their pages part by part in different modules, all using javascript. In fact, different modules are constructed on different server clusters.

Comment: The only one legal way to interact with users' data from facebook is through API.

Answer (score 3):

just use facebook graph, so much easier to get the info in json format than regexing html

open this in chrome or some decent browser that knows what to do with json,

http://graph.facebook.com/php

```
{
   "id": "6358087478",
   "name": "PHP",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/41787_6358087478_3246078_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/PHP",
   "category": "Product/service",
   "likes": 117991,
   "website": "www.php.net",
   "username": "PHP",
   "founded": "1994"
}
```

Comment: I dont want to go for open graph api. Because it wont return what the user likes, eg: sports, movies, music etc...

Comment: Yes it will. See this page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Answer (score 1):

Better way to get any details of any particular user is to build a facebook application and use the API provided by them..

The authentication API can be used to get all information(including email, likes location etc.,) about a specific user

And facebook will surely hide user information due to privacy terms..

The best to way to start is to read on this .. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

I tried with search engine user agent. It works folks!

```
$userAgent = 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)';
$url = "http://www.facebook.com/USERNAME";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Sorry folks, the above anwser is not correct. Facebook html pages cannot be scrapped too easily. They have high security restriction like trusted user-agent checks, trusted IP checks and captcha check.