# Coldfusion CFHTTP login to Facebook maintain session

Tags: facebook, coldfusion

How do you login to facebook via cfhttp and maintain session?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this, ['Facebook ColdFusion SDK'](http://facebooksdk.riaforge.org/).

Comment: I tried it and it only works in cf 9 coz of the import function. I should get cf 9 first :).

Comment: Yeah the whole thing's in cfscript.  Alternatively, Railo should work too.  Or you could rewrite it yourself into CFML!

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend using ['Facebook ColdFusion SDK'](http://facebooksdk.riaforge.org/) but if you are looking to scrape data from Facebook then you may want to take a look at [Ben Nadel's](http://www.bennadel.com/) component for maintaining a session across multiple `cfhttp` requests.

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/725-Maintaining-Sessions-Across-Multiple-ColdFusion-CFHttp-Requests.htm

http://www.bennadel.com/projects/cfhttp-session.htm

Comment: Instead of just applying a -1, could you provide some feedback for improving my answer?

Comment: I expect because your answer doesn't contain any content; it's just links to somewhere else. Linkrot happens, you know.

Comment: It would be great to see a sample login using Bennadel's script. I tried Bennadels script but cant get it to work.

Comment: Upon looking into this further. I've determined that using cfhttp to scrape data from Facebook is [likely possible](http://ruel.me/blog/2010/11/26/scrape-your-facebook-friends-contact-info-with-python/) but [more difficult](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5580650) than I first anticipated and apparently could lead to [legal complications](http://petewarden.typepad.com/searchbrowser/2010/04/how-i-got-sued-by-facebook.html).